# jsoup and cipher suite SSL

Tags: java, ssl, jsoup

Can I choose the ciphers used by jsoup when make a SSL connection?
I have java 7 and lastest version of jsoup but when jsoup make a SSL connection it never connect with the best cipher supported by web server. Can I force the choose?

EDIT

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import java.io.IOException;

public class PreferredCipherSuiteSSLSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory 
{
private final SSLSocketFactory delegate;

public PreferredCipherSuiteSSLSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory delegate) 
{
    this.delegate = delegate;
}
public PreferredCipherSuiteSSLSocketFactory() 
{
    this.delegate = HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultSSLSocketFactory();
}

@Override
public String[] getDefaultCipherSuites() 
{
    return setupPreferredDefaultCipherSuites(this.delegate);
}

@Override
public String[] getSupportedCipherSuites() 
{
    return setupPreferredSupportedCipherSuites(this.delegate);
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(String arg0, int arg1) throws IOException, UnknownHostException 
{
    Socket socket = this.delegate.createSocket(arg0, arg1);
    String[] cipherSuites = setupPreferredDefaultCipherSuites(delegate);
    ((SSLSocket)socket).setEnabledCipherSuites(cipherSuites);

    return socket;
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(InetAddress arg0, int arg1) throws IOException 
{
    Socket socket = this.delegate.createSocket(arg0, arg1);
    String[] cipherSuites = setupPreferredDefaultCipherSuites(delegate);
    ((SSLSocket)socket).setEnabledCipherSuites(cipherSuites);

    return socket;
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(Socket arg0, String arg1, int arg2, boolean arg3) throws IOException
{
    Socket socket = this.delegate.createSocket(arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3);
    String[] cipherSuites = setupPreferredDefaultCipherSuites(delegate);
    ((SSLSocket)socket).setEnabledCipherSuites(cipherSuites);

    return socket;
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(String arg0, int arg1, InetAddress arg2, int arg3) throws IOException, UnknownHostException 
{
    Socket socket = this.delegate.createSocket(arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3);
    String[] cipherSuites = setupPreferredDefaultCipherSuites(delegate);
    ((SSLSocket)socket).setEnabledCipherSuites(cipherSuites);

    return socket;
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(InetAddress arg0, int arg1, InetAddress arg2, int arg3) throws IOException 
{
    Socket socket = this.delegate.createSocket(arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3);
    String[] cipherSuites = setupPreferredDefaultCipherSuites(delegate);
    ((SSLSocket)socket).setEnabledCipherSuites(cipherSuites);

    return socket;
}

private static String[] setupPreferredDefaultCipherSuites(SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory) 
{
    ArrayList<String> suitesList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(sslSocketFactory.getSupportedCipherSuites()));
    ArrayList<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(String s : suitesList)
    {
        if(s.indexOf("ECDHE")!=-1)
            newList.add(s);
    }
    return newList.toArray(new String[newList.size()]);
}

private static String[] setupPreferredSupportedCipherSuites(SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory) 
{
    ArrayList<String> suitesList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(sslSocketFactory.getSupportedCipherSuites()));
    ArrayList<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(String s : suitesList)
    {
        if(s.indexOf("ECDHE")!=-1)
            newList.add(s);
    }
    return newList.toArray(new String[newList.size()]);
}
}
```

in my class

```
    PreferredCipherSuiteSSLSocketFactory objPrefCipher = new PreferredCipherSuiteSSLSocketFactory();
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(objPrefCipher);
```

now jsoup when connect to https use only cipher with ECDHE.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I force the choose?

No. The SSL server chooses the cipher suite, not the client. Unless you've done something to alter the enabled cipher suites, you should get whatever the server chooses among the many dozen supported by Java.

Comment: Yes I can force the choose. When I set the enabled cipher suites with only my cipher, the server if is supported choose it. I developed a simple class

Comment: If and only if the server supports that suite. The server still chooses. It isn't a good idea.